How to print an arabic text bill with a bluetooth printer in flutter
i have a flutter app and i need to print an arabic text bill with a bluetooth thermal printer
am using print_bluetooth_thermal package to find the bluetooth printers
and my thermal receipt printer model is 'MP210'
and using esc_pos_utils_plus to make the receipt and print it
like you see here in this code:
// Initialize printer
bool isConnected = await PrintBluetoothThermal.connectionStatus;
if (!isConnected) {
 await PrintBluetoothThermal.connect(
  macPrinterAddress: selectedPrinter!.macAdress,
 );
}

// Configure paper size and style
final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
final generator =
Generator(is58mm ? PaperSize.mm58 : PaperSize.mm80, profile);

// Build Bill
List<int> bytes = [];
// i want 'مرحبا' text instead of the 'Hello' text
bytes += generator.text(
        'Hello',
        styles: const PosStyles(
          bold: true,
          align: PosAlign.center,
          height: PosTextSize.size1,
          width: PosTextSize.size1,
        ),
      );
// Cut
bytes += generator.cut();

// Send
await PrintBluetoothThermal.writeBytes(bytes);

// Disconnect
await PrintBluetoothThermal.disconnect;

the problem is i want to print an arabic text in the bill
bc esc_pos_utils_plus  dosen`t support diffrent fonts
i tryed to make a pdf bill but the problem is it cant be printer with the packages above.
i cant print the pdf bill from the bluetooth printer with out a third party app like raw.bt
and i tryed convirting the pdf to an image but it didn`t turn that good bc it takes alot of time to print the receipt and the bill allways show to be not the center  and sometimes the letters are coded like this '%$^#' ...
any solutions ♥

I was searching for the same thing after trying more than one solution I used flutter_screen_shot
it will capture the screen or the widget you want to prints , then you will pass the bytes to the printer
  ScreenshotController screenshotController =
      ScreenshotController(); //Capture!!
  screenshotController
      .captureFromWidget(Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 5.0),
            color: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
          child: Text("This is an invisible widget")))
      .then((bytesImg) async {
    final generator =  Generator(is58mm ? PaperSize.mm58 : PaperSize.mm80, profile);

   final image = Imag.decodeImage(bytesImg);
    
    bytes += generator.image(image);
    bytes += generator.cut();

   await PrintBluetoothThermal.writeBytes(bytes);

   // Disconnect
   await PrintBluetoothThermal.disconnect;
  });


Unfortunately it didnt work for my thermal receipt printer model 'MP210'
bc its printing the receipt as codes '@!@#$#%N%SRD' something like that

@Samii ,
I am sorry for hearing this , I updated the answer I decode the image then used generator.Image to update the bytes array hope it will works with you this time

I would also recommend to print small Text only to know what would cause the issue and for better debugging
